# Bounded sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We have the following sequences:

$a_n=n+sin(n+3^n)$

$b_n=\frac{{(-1)^n}(n+1)}{3\sqrt{n^2+7}}$

Show that $a_n$ is non bounded and $b_n$ is bounded. Also show that the subsequences $b_{2n}$ and $b_{2n-1}$ are convergent.

My work: $a_n<n+1$ and as $n\rightarrow∞$ $a_n<$∞ , so $a_n$ is non bounded

For $b_n$ , $|\frac{{(-1)^n}(n+1)}{3\sqrt{n^2+7}}|=
\frac{n+1}{3\sqrt{n^2+7}}\rightarrow\frac{1}{3}$ as $n\rightarrow∞$
so we get $0<|b_n|<\frac{1}{3}$.

I don't know how to show that the subsequences are convergent. Maybe Weierstrass but i'm not sure.

Comment: Yes $b_n$ is bounded for Weierstrass EVT. But we can't conclude that $0<|b_n|<\frac{1}{3}$ we should find the maximum of $\frac{n+1}{3\sqrt{n^2+7}}$ or show that it is  monotonic.

Comment: What is EVT mean ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Comment: We should find the maximum or show that is monotonic to prove that the subsequences are convergent ?

Comment: I mean that we don't need to find the bounding limit to show that $b_n$ is bounded, continuity of f(x) and finite limit are sufficient by Weierstrass. To find the bounding limit we should find the maximum for $\frac{n+1}{3\sqrt{n^2+7}}$ that is not difficult but it is not necessary.

Comment: For instance we reach the max value for x=7 that is n=7 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+(x%2B1)%2F(3(x%5E2%2B7)%5E.5) that is indeed Greater than 1/3.

Comment: Yes i get that part. I can't prove the fact that the subsequences $b_{2n}$ and $b_{2n-1}$ are convergent.

Comment: Ok I add something about that!

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$a_n=n+\sin(n+3^n)>n-100 \to \infty$$

thus $a_n$ is not bounded and

$$-\frac{(n+1)}{3\sqrt{n^2+7}}\le b_n=\frac{{(-1)^n}(n+1)}{3\sqrt{n^2+7}}\le \frac{(n+1)}{3\sqrt{n^2+7}}$$

with $\frac{(n+1)}{3\sqrt{n^2+7}}$ bounded since $\frac{(x+1)}{3\sqrt{x^2+7}}$ is continuous and

$$\frac{(n+1)}{3\sqrt{n^2+7}}\to\frac13$$

thus for Weierstrass EVT $b_n$ is bounded.

Finally note that

$$b_{2n}=\frac{{(-1)^{2n}}(2n+1)}{3\sqrt{4n^2+7}}=\frac{(2n+1)}{3\sqrt{4n^2+7}}\to \frac13$$

$$b_{2n-1}=\frac{{(-1)^{2n-1}}(2n)}{3\sqrt{4n^2-4n+8}}=-\frac{2n}{3\sqrt{4n^2-4n+8}}\to -\frac13$$

Comment: Show $b_n$ is bounded below by -1/3 and not by 0 ?

Comment: you need to show that is bounded if I'm not wrong and thus it is good also for negative values, note that we have not shown that -1/3 and 1/3 are the bounding limit

Answer (score 0):

What you did for the first sequence is wrong. *Every* sequence has the property that $a_n<\infty$ for each $n$. What you should have notedis that $a_n\geqslant n-1$.

Comment: Yeah i get that now. Thank you very much